# Como resolver erro SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 1

Tags: php, ajax, json

Estou tentando fazer um cadastro simples mas estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 1

Não consegui resolver, o script está assim configurado:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#formulario').submit(function() {
            var dados = $('#formulario').serialize();           
            console.log(dados);
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'insertKit.php',
                data : dados,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.codigo == "1") {
                         $("#mensagem").html('AVISO!' + response.mensagem  + '');                       
                        window.setTimeout(function() {
                            $(".alert-success").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
                                $(this).remove();
                                window.location.href = "TabelaKits.php?id_produto=";
                            });
                        }, 3000);   
                    } else {
                         $("#mensagem").html('AVISO!' + response.mensagem  + '');
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                    $("#mensagem").html('AVISO! Ocorreu um erro ao gravar o kit, entre em contato com o suporte técnico do site.');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

A o script de inserção no banco está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao submeter o meu formulário é lançado em meu console as variáveis e seus valores:

> produto%5B%5D=2&numero%5B%5D=10022&quantidade%5B%5D=600&codigo%5B%5D=77&descricao%5B%5D=44545

E na sequência a mensagem de erro:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}abort: ƒ (a)always: ƒ ()complete: ƒ ()done: ƒ ()error: ƒ ()fail: ƒ ()getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)pipe: ƒ ()progress: ƒ ()promise: ƒ (a)readyState: 4responseText: "↵ERRO ao inserir registro no Banco"setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)state: ƒ ()status: 200statusCode: ƒ (a)statusText: "OK"success: ƒ ()then: ƒ ()__proto__: Object "parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse ()
    at m.parseJSON (jquery.js:8520)
    at Pb (jquery.js:8846)
    at x (jquery.js:9264)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.js:9718)
```

Li alguma coisa sobre nome de campos do formulário serem iguais, mas meu formulário está assim:

```html
<form id="formulario" action="" method="post" >   
   <div id="mensagem" class=""></div>   
 <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="products-table" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="15%">Produto</th>
    <th width="15%">Nº</th>
    <th width="16%">Qtde.</th>
    <th width="15%">Código</th>
    <th width="32%">Descrição</th>
    <th width="22%" class="actions">Ações</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="produto[]" value="<?php echo $produto; ?>" readonly ></td>                        
    <td><input type="text" name="numero[]" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantidade[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="codigo[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="descricao[]"></td>
    <td class="actions">
       <button class="btn btn-large btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6" style="text-align: left;">
       <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" onclick="AddTableRow(this)" type="button">Adicionar Linha</button>
       <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Gravar</button>
       <?php if ($totalRows_rcKits > 0) { ?>
       <a href="AlteraKits.php?produto=<?php echo $produto; ?>"  class="btn btn-warning"> Tabela</a>                           
       <?php } ?>
       <p align="center"><a href="CadProdutos.php" class="btn btn-primary">Voltar</a></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Localmente esse `insert` funciona perfeitamente.

Mais um detalhe que deixei passar é que está sempre caindo na mensagem de exceção:

> $("#mensagem").html('AVISO! Ocorreu um erro ao gravar o kit, entre em contato com o suporte técnico do site.');

Conforme solicitado segue a imagem da aba Network:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por que o código PHP está como imagem? Qual é o valor de `dados` enviado pela requisição?

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss, não consegui colocar o código pois ficou todo desconfigurado. O valor de dados é esse:
produto%5B%5D=2&numero%5B%5D=10022&quantidade%5B%5D=600&codigo%5B%5D=77&descricao%5B%5D=44545

Comment: A requisição foi feita pelo navegador (verificar através das ferramentas de desenvolvedor, aba Network)? Se sim, qual foi a resposta HTTP obtida, principalmente o corpo da resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a mensagem de erro do console, há um erro de sintaxe no `json`. Ao tentar converter a string, há um inesperado `token E`. Isso ocorre porque o seu código está "morrendo" na `query` do `INSERT`. O retorno que o Ajax recebe é:

```
ERRO ao inserir registro no Banco
```

Ou um simples aviso de alerta do php antes de exibir o json. O que já bastaria para dar erro de sintaxe.

No `insert` o erro está na string da query. Você está tentando inserir o que, provavelmente, é string sem aspas por exemplo. O que gera um erro. Além disso, com arrays, eu acho melhor você trabalhar concatenando a `string` assim:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO kits VALUES(".$Produto[$i].",'".$Descricao[$i]."')";
//                                                 ^   aspas simples  ^ - sem isso pode gerar erro
```

Podem ter mais outros erros...

Comment: Olá @AndreiCoelho, valeu pela dica.

Comment: @adventistapr tranquilo! Ainda dá para melhorar mais o código em php, mas eu precisaria dele escrito.

Comment: @adventistapr outra coisa ... esse `or die()` no seu caso, tem que ser retirado do código antes de ir em produção.

Comment: Sim, estava testando localmente, mas valeu pela dica.